# cv2.imshow() function is opening a window that always says (not responding) - python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, spyder

[image]

- To change Spyder setting: Go to Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Backend: Automatic (Change backend from Inline to Automatic) I can do these types it is not working what shall i do
- spyder version i using 5.4.2
- Python 3.9.16

if any one knows this problem fixed me

Comment: Provide a [mre]

Comment: Pls send the code for help

Comment: please add cv2.waitkey(0) at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to after **cv2.imshow**:

```py
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```